# How to combine several reports written in LaTeX with a contents for them

Tags: table-of-contents

an interesting question is how to combine several lab report written in LaTeX into one document. Of-course, few things are essential to take account to. For example, a contents list, unifying fig and table numbers, etc. Any suggestion or worked example would be helpful.

My current code is

```
\documentclass{report}
% same configuration as for your lab reports (to be compatible with this one)

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{cleaning wafer}
\input{lab1.tex}
% and so on, until
\part{E-beam evaporation}
\input{lab5.tex}

\end{document}
```

Here is an error

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the error persist?

Answer (score 1):

I consider your lab reports to be like this one:

```
\documentclass{report}

% configuration
\title{Lab i}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\input{content/lab-i-body.tex} % this is important

\end{document}
```

And the content of `content/lab-i-body.tex` looks like this:

```
\chapter{Presets}
% and so on, including figures and tables
```

And the collection of the lab reports will look like this:

```
\documentclass{book}

% same configuration as for your lab reports (to be compatible with this one), but:
\title{Collected Lab Reports}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\part{Title of Lab 1}
\input{lab-1-body.tex}
% and so on, until
\part{Title of Lab n}
\input{lab-n-body.tex}

\end{document}
```

And because `book` is a "bigger" class than `report`, that mean's the `chapter`s will be "collected" by the `part`s like `subsection`s are "collected" by `section`s, you don't have to adjust anything inside the `lab-i-body.tex` files. `figure`s and `table`s will be counted as expected because they are now part of a single document.

Comment: @Ecofritza can you write a pseudo code here, that I can follow it

Comment: For whole chapters you can use  also  [\include](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include). On the other hand, it is not the needed specify the  extension `.tex`  within the  `\input` command.

Comment: @ Ecofritze : I updated the problems statement above for the error that I got after I used your code.

Comment: @Mohammad: Try `\title{My Lab Reports}` in your preamble or remove `\maketitle`. You should replace it by your preferred title.

Comment: @ Ecofritze, I deleted \maketitle. Now I have new error saying that \documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle} while I recommended above in the answer use \documentclass{book}. In fact, the separate reports are in \documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}. Any idea how to fix this? I have uploaded error message in the problem statement.

Comment: No answers yet!

Comment: @Mohammad: It seem's that you are `\input`ing the whole lab report file, which starts with `\documentclass`. Be sure to only `\input` the inner part of your document as mentioned in my original post. You use some kind of article, so the "biggest" sectioning command available is `\section`. By "inner part of your document" I mean everything between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` (excluding these two) --- each should start with `\section{Title One}`.

Comment: It would be easier if you could provide a MWE, or a minimal non-working example in your case. And by the way, take a look at https://support.apple.com/en-la/HT201361 --- using cmd+shift+4 and space afterwards, you can take better looking screenshots of single windows.